# A problem on compositions of functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, elementary-functions

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x-1 & x \geq 0 \\ 1-x & x <0 \end{cases}$$

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x& x\geq 0 \\ x^2 & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

It asks me for the compositions $f(g(x))$.

What I did: it seemed easy to me, since

$$f(g(x)) = \begin{cases} x-1 & x \geq 0 \\ 1-x^2 & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

$$g(f(x)) = \begin{cases} x-1 & x \geq 0 \\ (1-x)^2 & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

Instead in the solution there is:

$$g(f(x)) = \begin{cases} 1-x & x < 0 \\ (x-1)^2 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\ x-1 & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

I don't get that solution. Some clarifications?

Comment: If $x \ge 0$, what can you say about $x-1$?  Is it always true that if $x \ge 0$, then $g(f(x)) = x-1$?

Comment: Your answer for $f(g(x))$ is also wrong in the $x < 0$ case.

Comment: @L.F. Uhm in the book it was correct... I'll check it again

Comment: @XanderHenderson Perhaps my error was to think that the "only" condition was about $x$. I mean it says just when $x$ is positive or negative, not when the whole function is $>$ o $<$...

Comment: @Numb3rs When you evaluate $g(f(x))$, the function $g$ doesn't "see" the variable $x$.  All it sees is the value of $f(x)$.  So consider:  what is $g(f(1/2))$?  From the definition of $f$, $$f(1/2) = 1/2 - 1 = -1/2.$$  So what is $g(-1/2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*.  To see why your answer
$$
(\color{red}{\times}) \qquad f(g(x)) = \begin{cases}
    x - 1 & \text{if } x \ge 0, \\
    1 - x^2 & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
is incorrect, consider $f(g(-2))$.  Clearly
$$
g(-2) = (-2)^2 = 4,
$$
so
$$
f(g(-2)) = f(4) = 4 - 1 = 3.
$$
However, your answer suggests that
$$
(\color{red}{\times}) \qquad f(g(-2)) = 1 - (-2)^2 = -3.
$$
Try to identify the mistake that caused this discrepancy.
Then, use this understanding to fix your expressions for $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$.

Here's an additional hint in case you cannot find the mistake.

> When evaluating $f(g(x))$ using the piecewise definition of $f$, we need to case on whether $g(x) \ge 0$ or $g(x) < 0$ rather than case on whether $x \ge 0$ or $x < 0$.  The variable $x$ in the expression $f(g(x))$ is not the same variable as the variable $x$ in the expression $f(x)$.
>  In other words, when evaluating $f(g(\color{red}{x}))$ using the definition $$ f(\color{blue}{x}) = \begin{cases} \color{blue}{x} - 1 & \text{if } \color{blue}{x} \ge 0, \\ 1 - \color{blue}{x} & \text{if } \color{blue}{x} < 0, \end{cases} $$ we are making the variable binding $\color{blue}{x} = g(\color{red}{x})$ so that $f(\color{blue}{x}) = f(g(\color{red}{x}))$.  The variables $\color{red}{x}$ and $\color{blue}{x}$ are distinct and should not be conflated.

Comment: Got it!! Thak you! P.s. I think you wanted to write $f(g(-2))$ ^^

Comment: @Numb3rs Nice catch!  I was originally going to use $f(g(-1))$, but then I realized $f(g(-1)) = 0 = -0$ would ruin the example ...